# Converstion of seconds in minutes

Tags: iphone, ios5, nstimeinterval

I have to change seconds into minutes, hours.
I am already using this code:

```
   int minutes = floor(seconds/60);
   int sec = trunc(seconds - minutes * 60);
   int hours1 = floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
```

It works fine, but when `"60 minutes"` completed it gives `01:61:01` I want timer in this format `01:01:01`.
i.e. my minutes does not convert after 60 minutes.

Please suggest me or help me. I am searching lots of code but still not find exact solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "completed" ? You should provice more code so we can have a clearer view.

Comment: For minutes, you need to use %60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can calculate minutes from seconds with bellow formula...

```
int minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
```

see the whole code for hours,minutes and seconds bellow...

```
int hours, minutes, seconds;
hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
seconds = (secondsLeft %3600) % 60;
NSLog(@"\nTime is => %02d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,seconds);
```

**Output is :** Time is 00:00:06

Comment: @Abha if you put this code `int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;` instead of `int minutes = floor(seconds/60);` then you get minuts maximum `60` and after start from `00` use my above code and you will get whole perfect output :)

Answer (score 1):

I have converted secs to minutes.Hope this can help you.

```
    float playListMinsLocal=floorf(songObj.songTime.floatValue);
    float playListSecsLocal=songObj.songTime.floatValue-playListMinsLocal+.001;
    float playListTotalSecs=(playListMinsLocal*60)+(playListSecsLocal*100);
    playListMins+=(int)playListTotalSecs/60;
    playListSecs+=(int)playListTotalSecs%60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this:

```
int seconds = mySeconds % 60; 
int minutes = (mySeconds / 60) % 60; 
int hours = mySeconds / 3600;
```